# Pass additional parameters to handsontable autocomplete source function

Tags: handsontable

I am implementing HandsOnTable autocomplete ajax as documented here: https://docs.handsontable.com/3.0.0/demo-autocomplete.html#strict-ajax

But I would like to pass **additional** parameter to the autocomplete `source` function, something like `row.id` below:

```
hot3 = new Handsontable(container3, {
    data: getCarData(),
    colHeaders: ['Car', 'Year', 'Chassis color', 'Bumper color'],
    columns: [
      {
        type: 'autocomplete',
        source: function (query, process, row.id) {
          $.ajax({
            //url: 'php/cars.php', // commented out because our website is hosted as a set of static pages
            url: 'scripts/json/autocomplete.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
              query: query
            },
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.handsontable.com/3.0.0/demo-autocomplete.html#strict-ajax), `source` function only accepts two parameters (`query` and `process`), anyone knows how can I pass additional parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add an argument to `source` function. It does not "accept" parameters, it provides. This function is called internally by Handsontable with predefined arguments.

But you can still access the data you are looking for. Check the context that `source` function is called with. It's a `ColumnSettings` object which contains (among others) column and row ids.

Something like:

```
columns: [
  {
    type: 'autocomplete',
    source: function (query, process) {
      var rowId = this.row;
      var columnId = this.col;

      $.ajax({
        ... // do whatever you want
      });
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks!.. I didn't find `ColumnSettings` as you mentioned, but I did manage to retrieve the entire row like so: `const sourceRow = this.instance.getSourceData();` From there I can pick whatever column I want and pass it to the server.